# My swift code doesn't scan barcode created with tcpdf?

Tags: ios, swift, barcode-scanner, scanning

I add some metadataObjectTypes in my swift code in the hope my app would scan the barcodes i have created with php tcpdf. But unfortunatly it doesn't, is there a metadataObjectType i have missed?

This is part of the swift code

```
metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode,AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code]
```

And i am using this tcpdf php file [Example 1d barcode](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/barcodes/example_1d_html.html)

But the app scans this barcode from developer.apple.com without a problem:
[image]

Comment: Your barcode is probably not conform to any of the types you declare (Captain Obvious, yeah, but I can't see any other reason).

Comment: yeah, might be the case. I was using an physical barcode scanner and didn't realise my app didn't scane the barcode. Due to tight deadline i replace one of the bars (had 1 one barcode bar rotated and one normal) for a QRcode which my app can scan.